# Renaming excel files based on content

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to rename my excel files in a folder based on the content of cell a1, I am using pandas to parse the files and store the value of cell a1, then using that value to rename the file.

The code is as follows:

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob

source_dir = r'C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\Desktop\RenameFolder'

file_names = glob.glob(os.path.join(source_dir, '*.xlsx'))

for file_name in file_names:
    df1 = pd.read_excel(file_name)
    new_name = df1.iat[0,0]
    # print (new_name)
    file_name.rename(file_name.with_name(new_name))
```

I get the following traceback:

```
C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\python.exe C:/Users/Ahmed_Abdelmuniem/PycharmProjects/Renamer/main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Ahmed_Abdelmuniem\PycharmProjects\Renamer\main.py", line 13, in <module>
    file_name.rename(file_name.with_name(f"new_name"))
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'rename'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I am not sure what it means by AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'rename', as the value stored in new_name is a str, I tested it out with print. It produces the following result:

```
XXX.xlsx
YYY.xlsx
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `file_name` you are trying to rename is just a `str`, which does not contain the `rename` method. You can rename a file using `os.rename`. See code below.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import glob

source_dir = ''

file_names = glob.glob(os.path.join(source_dir, '*.xlsx'))

for file_name in file_names:
    df1 = pd.read_excel(file_name)
    new_name = df1.iat[0,0]
    os.rename(os.path.join(source_dir, file_name), os.path.join(source_dir,new_name+".xlsx"))
```

Comment: Thank you so very much, it worked. However, I don't understand the os module very well, why did your os.rename work while my file_rename not work?

Comment: The variable `file_rename` is a `str` and not the file itself. You could try the same for an arbitrary string like `file_name = 'foo'` and would still get the same error. Strings do not contain the `rename` method. Try printing `file_name`. Contrary to this, `os` is a python module and contains methods such as `rename()`. See: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-rename-method/#:~:text=rename()%20method%20in%20Python,to%20specified%20destination%20file%2Fdirectory.